# How to throw a warning in MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, signals, warnings

Currently I have exit handlers:

```
DECLARE c_invalidParam CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '48000';
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR c_invalidParam
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    SELECT 'I' INTO out_resultCode;
    SELECT '0' INTO out_accountId;
    RESIGNAL;
END;

IF in_username = ''
THEN
    SIGNAL c_invalidParam
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'sp_test: username may not be empty';
END IF;
```

This makes my stored procedure to exit. How do I throw a warning and exit the stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following procedure signals an error or warning depending on the value of pval, its input parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p (pval INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE specialty CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
  IF pval = 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000';
  ELSEIF pval = 1 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
  ELSEIF pval = 2 THEN
    SIGNAL specialty
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
  ELSE
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'A warning occurred', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1000;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1001;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: This is directly from the manual and should have been attributed https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html